# Getting maximum extent of 2 different layers for map display using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, extents

In the QGIS 3 layout, I would like to display two layers and for this I need their combined maximum extent. So far I've got:

```py
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis.utils
import shutil
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui


project = QgsProject.instance()
project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(21781))

iface.mainWindow().blockSignals(True)


# add vector layer
shplayer = iface.addVectorLayer("C:\\MyData\\A300.shp", "A300", "ogr")
shplayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2056))
project.addMapLayer(shplayer)

# add raster layer 1
rlayer1 = iface.addRasterLayer("C:\\MyData\\Area_1.asc", "Area1")
rlayer1.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2056))
project.addMapLayer(rlayer1)

# find max extent of all layers
ext_r = rlayer1.extent().toString().replace(":",",").split(',') #(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
ext_shp = shplayer.extent().toString().replace(":",",").split(',')
ext_all = [min(ext_r1[0],ext_shp [0]), max(ext_r1[1],ext_shp [1]), min(ext_r1[2],ext_shp [2]), max(ext_r1[3],ext_shp [3])]



#-- Create custom caneva
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout_name = 'my_custom_layout'
layout_list = manager.printLayouts()

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.setName(layout_name)
layout.initializeDefaults()
manager.addLayout(layout)

#--- create map item (shapefile, raster 1)

map1 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout) # create Layout item
map1.setRect(QRectF(10, 10, 210, 90)) # set the map item rectangle
map1.setPos(10,10) # map item upper left corner position
map1.setFrameEnabled(True) # to have a map black border

ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers([shplayer, rlayer1]) # set layers to be mapped


# !! here I'd like the max extent of both layers! QgsRectangle(rlayer1.extent() + shplayer.extent())
map1_extent = QgsRectangle(float(ext_all[0]), float(ext_all[2]), float(ext_all[1]), float(ext_all[3])) # must be (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) but does not work!
map1_extent.scale(1.0)
ms.setExtent(map1_extent)
map1.setExtent(map1_extent)

layout.addLayoutItem(map1)
map1.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10,10))
map1.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(210,90))


# export map in .pdf
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf("C:\\mapstest.pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())


project.write()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepare this for your case, the [QgsRectangle](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRectangle.html#ab8a73ddc15774addc822550266f886c9). have a function that allow combine the extends, the name of the function is this, **combineExtentWith**

you can use in your code like this:

```
ext = rlayer1.extent()
ext_shp = shplayer.extent()
ext.combineExtentWith(ext_shp)
```

in this case the object ext will be ext_all, you have to place here:

```
map_extent = ext
```

because this is a QgsRectangle, I prove your code with this changes and worked.

Comment: "combineExtentWith" did the trick! Thanks a lot :-)